# Styling an inline list

Tags: html, css

I am unsure how to position text within the `<ul>` container without the `<li>` overflowing. What am I doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/ewAtr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As prodigitalson said, the height of `div#listed` should be inclusive of margin and border widths of the `li`'s.

I would prefer using `height:auto` for the div and using `clearfix` for `ul`, like in this edited fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rJkL8/

Answer (score 1):

You are not accounting for the margin and border width.

Answer (score 0):

Try using last child to target the last li.

Answer (score 0):

```
  #listed {
    height: 50px;
    width: 330px;

  }

  #listed ul {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    list-style-type:none;

  }

  li.item {

     float: left;
     margin-top:10px;
  }

  #listed ul li a {

     font-family: "lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
     font-size: 15px;
     color: blue;
     text-align: center;
     text-decoration: none;
     padding:15px 10px;
     border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
     border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
  }

  #listed ul li a:hover{
     font-family: "lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
     font-size: 15px;
     color: white;
     background-color: blue;
     text-align: center;
     text-decoration: none;
  }    ​
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty way is to overflow:hidden on the parent div as seen in [this updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ewAtr/17/)